# Scala generics subtypes

Tags: scala, generics, types

I am lost in scala generics.

I need a method `storeUnit` which accepts `Unit`'s subclasses's instances (e.q. `Visit`) and returns `StoredUnit`'s subclasses's instances (e.q. `StoredVisit`) but I am getting compilation errors.

```
trait StatsUnit { val ip: String } 
case class Visit(ip: String) extends StatsUnit
case class Click(ip: String) extends StatsUnit

trait StoredStatsUnit extends StatsUnit { val id: String }
case class StoredVisit(id: String, ip: String) extends StoredStatsUnit
case class StoredClick(id: String, ip: String) extends StoredStatsUnit

def storeUnit[A <: StatsUnit, B <: StoredStatsUnit](statsUnit: A): B = {
  statsUnit match {
    case x: Visit => StoredVisit("myid", x.ip)
    case x: Click => StoredClick("myid", x.ip)
  }
}

/tmp/1.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.StoredVisit
 required: B
    case x: Visit => StoredVisit("myid", x.ip)
                                    ^
/tmp/1.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.StoredClick
 required: B
    case x: Click => StoredClick("myid", x.ip)
```

Comment: Oh, my! **Do not** define the name `Unit`! It's a very important built-in Scala type!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making B generic? You're promising to return a B, but then returning a fixed type (StoredVisit).

Comment: @themel I edited the question to clarify why I need B to be a generic.

Comment: Your type for `storeUnit` says it can be called as `storeUnit[Visit, StoredClick](Visit("")): StoredClick`. Obviously, this doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment first:

1. Don't name your trait `Unit`! `Unit` has specific meaning in Scala - it's equivalent to Java's `void` - and shadowing that definition is only going to cause troubles!

However, the problem here is that you specify that your method will return an instance of `B` and then you try to return something of type `StoredVisit`. You don't need `B` at all in this example, so the following will work fine:

```
def storeUnit[A <: StatsUnit](unit: A): StoredStatsUnit = {
  StoredVisit("myid", unit.ip)
}
```

Comment: While Scala's `Unit` is mapped (bidirectionally) to Java's `void`, it's a little misleading to call them equivalents. There are no values of type `void` in Java but there is (exactly) one value of type `Unit` in Scala (hence the name `Unit`). That value of type `Unit` is notated `()`.

Comment: @Impredicative first version of my question was mistakenly simplyfied and I corrected it to explain why I need B to be a subclass of StoredStatsUnit

Comment: @Randall That's true. I used 'equivalent' mostly to emphasize the "really don't do this!" aspect, rather than exactly explaining what it is.

Comment: @RandallSchulz Impredicative after several minutes of thinking I understood your thoughts. I edited your answer to be consistent with edits in the question.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let's lie to the compiler to make the code compile, and then I'll show what the compiler is complaining about. First:

```
scala> def storeUnit[A <: StatsUnit, B <: StoredStatsUnit](unit: A): B = {
     |   StoredVisit("myid", unit.ip).asInstanceOf[B]
     | }
storeUnit: [A <: StatsUnit, B <: StoredStatsUnit](unit: A)B
```

Now let's create another subclass of `StoredStatsUnit`:

```
case class UnStoredVisit(id: String, ip: String, n: Int) extends StoredStatsUnit
```

And now let's show why the compiler was complaining about that method definition:

```
scala> val visit: UnStoredVisit = storeUnit(Visit("1.2.3.4"))
java.lang.ClassCastException: StoredVisit cannot be cast to UnStoredVisit
```

In other words, you are *not* returning a parameterized B which is an arbitrary subclass of `StoredStatsUnit`. You are returning a `StoredVisit`, which is one specific subclass of it.

Answer (score 1):

`B` is a subtype of `StoredUnit` and `StoredVisit` is a subtype of `StoredUnit` but there is no valid inference that `StoredVisit` is compatible with `B`.

Comment: So... how does one fix that.